# How do I add a circuit to disable this system during the night?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

Key bits of circuit illustrated below:

- buzzer (J1) activates at interval, triggered internally by IC pin 4
- when solar panel low (not making 1.6v) triggers IC pin 7 via Q2, which triggers IC pin 2/3 High (3v) and light led
- buzzer can be plugged in & out, when plugged in it activates the timed buzz intervals from the IC via Q3 and IC pin 8

I want to mod it so when at night the buzzer doesnt run

I want to use the solar circuit to trigger 'darkness'

[image]

Comment: What does J1 connect to in the schematic? Also, how much current does the buzzer use?

Comment: Q1 and Q2 are drawn incorrectly - they should be NPN not PNP

Comment: q1/q2 are s8050, that is PNP no ?, J1 goes into an amplifier transistor, buzzer(j1) draws 17ma

Comment: @HaydenThring s8050 are npn http://www.es.co.th/schemetic/pdf/S8050.pdf You might need to fix your schematic. Part number for the IC would be good too.

Comment: ic is unmarked :( , why does it say pnp here: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/33773/WINGS/S8050/+237JWUyGLGybuC-zB+/datasheet.pdf

Comment: the full number is: s8050 d331

Comment: i have corrected the original schematic

Comment: I think this question has received far too much attention and mainly because the circuit diagram does not give enough detail. What is IC1 - I've scanned the comments and proposed answers including those that are deleted and I can't find it. This question, as it is currently would be better served by being deleted and started afresh with a decent circuit diagram and clear/decent links to parts.

Comment: it has actually been brought up and answered, the IC is unmarked, i have no idea what it is

Comment: I think you may have connected the PNP wrong in the schematic: the base is hooked up to the line that should be driven, that doesn't seem right...

Comment: ive checked it and i believe its right, what actually happens is the buzzer switches the system on, when plugged in it lets 3.3v flow to pin 8 IC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Q2 has been changed into a NPN, I am less confident about this, but theoretically this should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcc8Na.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NPN Q1 should, when Pin 2/3 are high and the led is lit (Meaning Pin 7 is high/floating and the Solar Cell is not producing voltage), be turned on, creating a small short circuit (limited by R6). This should bring Q1's collector and Q2's base close to ground potential, which should deprive Q2 of current, preventing it from turning on.

Comment: thankyou, this is the sort of thing i was thinking of and bought some npn's to try it, but couldnt work it out, so came here, i will try this out

Comment: @Passerby - This looks wrong - If Q2 (originally labelled as Q1) is a PNP type then the emitter and collectors have been reversed. If Q2 (originally Q1) is an NPN  the circuit has been drawn incorrectly in the first place. This transistor has been identified as an S8050 type which is an NPN.  http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/154210/WEITRON/S8050.html

Comment: why does it say pnp here: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/33773/WINGS/S8050/+237JWUyGLGybuC-zB+/datasheet.pdf

Comment: @Passerby then how do you explain the direction of current shown by the emitter arrow from 0V to +V - something is wrong.

Comment: full number is s8050 d331, it appears i got the wrong icon in my original image...

Comment: i have corrected the original schematic

Comment: i tried it with a bc548 npn transistor and it didnt work ?

Comment: can you redo it it with how ive illustrated them now ?

Comment: ive updated the schematic again, tracing more of the circuit up river from the buzzer. there is a PNP transistor that when the speaker is plugged into the circuit allows 3.5v to pin 8 which is the +ve supply for the IC and activates everything. if i could switch that instead with the solar.

Comment: @HaydenThring The speaker being connected to ground on one side and a pnp base on the other makes no sense. No current would ever flow through it.

Comment: i likely have the pins shown wrong, how can i tell what pin is what ?

Comment: ok, i read the code wrong on that pnp, it is a S8550 which was easy enough to find a datasheet for, and it shows the middle pin being the base and that is what one of the leads of the buzzer is connected to ...

Comment: regardless your new modified circuit diagram works ! well done you get the bounty.

Comment: @HaydenThring good to hear.

Comment: thanks for sticking with it, will award bounty when allowed to

Answer (score 0):

The control should go between pin 4 and R1.  I would use a simple AND gate that has pin 4 of the IC as an input, and use a [photo-sensitive circuit](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2007/a-simple-and-cheap-dark-detecting-led-circuit/) to control the other input of the AND gate.

The link is for a "darkness detector" (turns on in the dark) but swapping the placement of the resistor and phototransistor should do it: when the phototransistor is in the light, it will connect the AND gate input to V+, and when it's dark, the 1k resistor holds the input to ground, blocking the signal from pin 4 of the IC.

Sorry about the photodiode: they don't have an element for a phototransistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgUTPK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wouldnt this circuit waste extra battery?

Comment: @Sherby: why's it matter?  You didn't mention anything about battery power.  AND gates don't draw that much, its a matter of implementation.

Comment: The current draw should be almost negligible if you use a CMOS AND gate.  Worst case let's call the phototransistor a short, R1 is connected to V+ (3.3V in the diagram) and the power is p = 3.3^2 / 1000=  about 11 mW, and that's a back of the envelope worst case.

Comment: I like this idea, but it occurs to me that there is already dark detection built into the circuit- the low of the solar cell.  I wonder if an AND gate using Pin 4 output and the solar cell line feeding Q2 would get the job done.

Comment: The solar cell looks like it's at a max of 1.6V, but I thought the same thing at first...

Comment: @Bob  Cool.  Good to know maybe I wasn't completely out where the busses don't run.

Comment: i should have specified that i wanted to use the solar circuit to trigger 'darkness'

Comment: also i just wantonly to add a transistor if possible

Comment: Couldn't  you just tie J1 to the solar collector?  When there's light, the panel has voltage potential, and the speaker can sound.  When there is no light, the speaker will essentially be tied to ground, and won't be able to sound.  This hit me several days ago in the car, but I forgot to write...

Answer (score 0):

Tie the wire coming out of J1 that leads to nothing to the solar collector's positive terminal.  When it's dark, there will be no power source for the speaker, and it is effectively turned off.

We don't know the voltage of the collector; if it's a higher voltage than what J1 is rated for, increase the serial resistance accordingly.

Comment: by J1 do you mean Q1 ? can you elaborate your answer with a diagram ? by tie do you mean with a transistor ? how ?

Comment: I mean connect the speaker wire next to the label J1 that doesn't connect to anything in your schematic to the solar cell's positive terminal.  No other parts are needed, just hook the wire to the solar cell, and when there's light, the speaker will be powered, and it will work, and when there isn't light, the speaker won't have a voltage source and so it won't work.

Comment: sorry i totally missed i had the buzzer labeled as J1... i did not draw that part of the circuit that has a pnp transistor and some other bits as an amplifier circuit, i will look into it though and get back.

Comment: ive updated the schematic again, tracing more of the circuit up river from the buzzer. there is a PNP transistor that when the speaker is plugged into the circuit allows 3.5v to pin 8 which is the +ve supply for the IC and activates everything. if i could switch that instead with the solar.

Answer (score 0):

To control the buzzer you can add a [LDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) to only disable to be triggered when its darkness. You can control the sensibility of light by the R7 that could be a 100k trimpot.

The rest of the circuit I doesn't change anything, just add the control to the buzzer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsewu7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ive had this suggestion and have tried to make it clear that i want to use the existing solar cell circuit to trigger light/dark, thanks anyway